question of an inequality involving dimension of harmonic homogenous polynomials
Let $P_n^d$ be homogenous polynomials of dimension d and $H_n^d$ be the space of homogenous harmonic polynomials meaning $\Delta P_n^d=0$ that is Laplacian operator applied to it is $0$. Now in a paper is the statement that since $\Delta P_n^d \subset P_n^d$   then $\dim H_n^d \le \dim P_n^d-\dim P_{n-2}^d$. I understand the part $\Delta P_n^d \subset P_n^d$ but how does and what does that have to do with or help in proving $\dim H_n^d \ge \dim P_n^d-\dim P_{n-2}^d$ ? Can anyone prove this statement. An intuitive proof would be ok as i know a rigorous proof would be extremely difficult.
